# mysql Stored procedure output many columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to declare output parameter to return an array or recordset?

If I try to get only one column this work OK

```
enter code here
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
  IN invar VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT col1 INTO outvar FROM my_table WHERE col1 = invar;
END;
```

But if I try to get many columns I don't know how to do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
  IN invar VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT col1,col2 INTO outvar FROM my_table WHERE col1 = invar;
END;
```

With outvar VARCHAR(255) I understand that **I can not** because is a STRING type, but with which type I need to declare the outvar to working with many columns

I need to get out some like this "Column_name1" => "Value" , "Column_name2" => "Value2" for use in PHP with $output_result->fetch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare another variable and store col1 and col2 value in different variable. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
  IN invar VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar1 VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar2 VARCHAR(255),
)
BEGIN
  SELECT col1,col2 INTO outvar1,outvar2 FROM my_table WHERE col1 = invar;
END;
```

Here col1 value will be in outvar1 and col2 value will be in outvar2

Answer (score 1):

You can also try concat. but later in php code you would need to explode.

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(
  IN invar VARCHAR(255),
  OUT outvar VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT CONCAT(col1,",",col2) INTO outvar FROM my_table WHERE col1 = invar;
END;